# Windows 10 hide user account picture on the login screen

Tags: windows-10-preview

I have seen some third party utilities that could do this in Windows 10. I have also found that deleting **all** image files in the following folders would also accomplish this task. Make sure you have backups in the event you wish to restore.

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures

C:\Users\Public\AccountPictures

%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures
```

However, beginning with Windows 10 build 14371 and higher the third party utilities have no effect. Likewise, deleting the images in the folders above has no effect. I cannot find where MS is pulling the user account picture from in these newer Windows 10 builds. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What tools specifically are not working?

Comment: Windows 10 Login Changer_1.5 by alphawaves is the most recent utility I used.  The others are no longer supported.

Comment: Only sites with downloads to the tool, appear to be malware swarms, I will past.  I can't help.